# Latent Growth Modeling in Lavaan

Tags: r, lavaan, growth-model

Lavaan newbie here.  I've been trying to specify a latent growth curve model in R for a few days now and been going through all the tutorials on the Lavaan website. The theoretical path is reasonably clear to me, however I am failing to translate my theoretical ideas (as in the attached path diagram) into a working lavaan code.
I would like to build such a model for a each of a total of 15 personality traits. Each personality trait was collected at three measurement times with 4 items each. Also, I would like to add age and gender as covariates, gradually I would also like age^2 and age^3 to see if these effects are more fitting.
Attached is my path diagram for an exemplary personality trait.

This is what my code looks like so far (exemplary for one of the 15 personality traits), but I am unfortunately getting very poor fits, even negative degrees of freedom in some cases.

```
lgcmAengst <- '
i =~ 1*T1NeuroAengstlichkeitMean + 1*T2NeuroAengstlichkeitMean + 1*T3NeuroAengstlichkeitMean 
s =~ 0*T1NeuroAengstlichkeitMean + 1*T2NeuroAengstlichkeitMean + 2*T3NeuroAengstlichkeitMean

i ~ SQ1_age + SQ1_sex
s ~ SQ1_age + SQ1_sex

'

lgcmAengstfit <- growth(lgcmAengst, data = daten)
summary(lgcmAengstfit, fit.measures=TRUE)
semPaths(lgcmAengstfit)
```

Does anyone have any ideas where errors could be?

Thanks so much in advance,
Mira

PS: TXNeuroAengstlichkeitMean is the mean out of the 4 items that have been collected at the measurement point[image: path diagram]

Comment: The only "error" you described is having negative *df*.  This model should have 1 *df* from the mean structure (because 2 factor means are used to reproduce 3 indicator means), and 1 *df* per predictor from the covariance structure (because each predicts 2 growth factors rather than 3 indicators).

Comment: Thank you so much Terrence, I really appreciate your help and feedback. In the next step I would like to add age^2 and age^3 to my model to see if these are having a significant effect on Intercept / Slope (whilst Age seems not to have). I have tried by just adding it into the code like, but I does not seem to work. 

lgcmEnergie <- '
i =~ 1*T1ExtraEnergieMean + 1*T2ExtraEnergieMean + 1*T3ExtraEnergieMean # 
s =~ 0*T1ExtraEnergieMean + 1*T2ExtraEnergieMean + 2*T3ExtraEnergieMean 

i ~ SQ1_age + SQ1_age^2 + SQ1_age^3 + SQ1_sex 
s ~ SQ1_age + SQ1_age^2 + SQ1_age^3 + SQ1_sex

'

Comment: Would you have an idea how to fix this and check for quadratic and cubic effects?

Comment: `lavaan` does not use formula objects.  You have to create new variables in your data.frame that are the squares and cubes of age, then explicitly add those "new variables" to your model syntax.

Comment: thank you so much, Terrence!